# Combobox in datagrid works only when I first right click it

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox, datagrid

I'm working in a large existing application and I've been having trouble with a combobox inside xaml. At first I thought I had a binding problem and tried several ways of binding it....

To my suprise, after relentless searching I accidentely right clicked on the combobox and then it worked just like that... (so the binding seems to work but only after I right click the combobox).. And Once I right click the combobox, it just keeps working... and this is the case for all comboboxes in the datagrid

Other comboboxes outside of datagrids, just work fine.

I thought there may be a problem in the app.xaml so I set the style to null... but still no luck...

I have no idea what the problem may be and can't find anywhere something similar...

Any ideas? Has this something to do with the combobox being inside the datagrid?

Here is the XAML:

```
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" IsReadOnly="false"
               AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NieuweBelligen, Mode=OneWay}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="2*"
                                Header="{Omschrijving}"
                                Binding="{Binding Omschrijving, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Adeling" Width="1*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ACollection}" DisplayMemberPath="AOmschrijving" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedAID, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                                  Style="{x:Null}">
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are always 2 kind of templates for DataGrid cells: `CellTemplate`and `CellEditTemplate` 
So if your row goes into edit mode, then the `CellEditTemplate` will be used instead of the regular  `CellTemplate`

Now you have 2 options really:

1. Define a template for the `CellEditTemplate`
2. Make the column `ReadOnly`, this way only the regular `CellTemplate` will be used.

If this still doesn't solve your problem, just leave a comment and update your question with the new code your tried.